# Adding x aesthetic to panel computation in ggplot2 extension

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I am writing a `ggplot` extension to use `GeomSegment` as the geom for ethogram plots. I am having some issues to include a proper `x` axis into the aesthetics. Right now, I'm hacking the `x` axis with a `1:length(behavior)` (see function definition below), and I think my approach needs to change to be able to have a proper `x` axis.

Here are the functions I am using to generate the new `stat_()`:

```
ethogram <- function(behavior){
  df <- 
    tibble::tibble(behavior = behavior,
                   time_col = 1:length(behavior)) %>% 
    dplyr::mutate(lg = dplyr::lag(behavior, default = "first frame"),
                  # check if there's continuity
                  flag = lg != behavior) %>% 
    dplyr::filter(flag) %>% 
    dplyr::mutate(time_end = dplyr::lead(time_col,
                                         n = 1,
                                         default = dplyr::last(time_col))) %>% 
    dplyr::rename(x = time_col,
                  xend = time_end)
  cols_to_keep <- c("x", "xend", "behavior")
  return(df[, cols_to_keep])
  
}

setup_data <- function(data, params){
  #if (anyDuplicated(data$group)) {
  #  data$group <- paste(data$group, seq_len(nrow(data)), sep = "-")
  #}
  if ("x" %in% names(data) == FALSE){
    data$x <- 1:nrow(data)
  }
  return(data)
  
}
```

And here's how I'm defining it:

```
StatEtho <- ggproto("StatEtho", Stat, 
                    setup_data = setup_data,
                      compute_panel = function(data, scales) {
                        print(head(data, n=10))
                        summ_data <- 
                          data %>% 
                          group_by(y) %>% 
                          summarise(ethogram(behavior)) %>% 
                          mutate(yend = y)
                        if ("colour" %in% names(data)){
                          color_df <- distinct(data, y, behavior, colour)
                          summ_data <- left_join(summ_data, color_df, by=c("y", "behavior"))
                        }
                        print(head(summ_data))
                        return(summ_data)
                      },
                      required_aes = c("y")
)


geom_ethogram <- function(mapping = NULL,
                          data = NULL,
                          stat = "etho",
                          position = "identity",
                          ...,
                          size=5,
                          arrow = NULL,
                          lineend = "butt",
                          linejoin = "round",
                          na.rm = FALSE,
                          show.legend = NA,
                          inherit.aes = TRUE) {
  layer(
    data = data,
    mapping = mapping,
    stat = stat,
    geom = GeomSegment,
    position = position,
    show.legend = show.legend,
    inherit.aes = inherit.aes,
    params = list(
      size=size,
      arrow = arrow,
      lineend = lineend,
      linejoin = linejoin,
      na.rm = na.rm,
      ...
    )
  )
}
```

I can check that my `ethogram()` function works and computes the limits needed for calling using `GeomSegment`:

```
> ethogram(df$target)
# A tibble: 571 × 3
       x  xend behavior
   <int> <int> <chr>   
 1     1     2 C       
 2     2     5 A       
 3     5     6 B       
 4     6     7 A       
 5     7     8 C
```

Here's a reproducible example:

```
df <- tibble::tibble(
    y = sort(rep(1:2, 500)),
    target = sample(LETTERS[1:4], size = 1000, 
                    replace = T, prob = c(0.6, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1))
)

ggplot(df, aes(y=y, behavior=target, color=target))+
  geom_ethogram()
```

[image]

### What I think is wrong:

I think the way I solved the `compute` function is suboptimal and generating problems:
I tried multiple ways to make this work using `compute_group()` but that gets rid of the temporal component (and that's why I'm trying to add the `x` values for the plot). Because I am relying on `summarise()` , I find myself having to put things back onto the data (like the `left_join` for `color`).

```
compute_panel = function(data, scales) {
                        print(head(data, n=10))
                        summ_data <- 
                          data %>% 
                          group_by(y) %>% 
                          summarise(ethogram(behavior)) %>% 
                          mutate(yend = y)
                        if ("colour" %in% names(data)){
                          color_df <- distinct(data, y, behavior, colour)
                          summ_data <- left_join(summ_data, color_df, by=c("y", "behavior"))
                        }
                        print(head(summ_data))
                        return(summ_data)
                      }
```

This is an example of a failure case. It doesn't throw errors, but the `1:length(behavior)` resolves to 1 because of the way `ggplot` is handling the call:

```
# This fails to produce expected result
# problem is length(behavior) is 1 when passed as the grouping
ggplot(df, aes(x=1:nrow(df), 
               y=target, 
               behavior=target, 
               color=target))+
  geom_ethogram() +
  facet_wrap(~y)
```

[image]

I would want to have `x` on my `aes()` to solve this issue and have a better dissociation of `y` and `behavior` variables.

### Update

Addressing the questions.

- What the input / output is supposed to be?

I was trying to keep the input minimal, initially only the sequence string. Later, I was planning to build on top of that (except the first one, all others exceed the scope of this question). Mainly:

1. x axis (this wouldn't be forced to be datetime, it can be numeric). I was hoping to handle it internally, if not provided, just do `1:length(behavior)` somewhere. We need this to calculate the start and end of the segments, but it's basically scaling.
2. display example individuals from both groups (using facets)
3. display one individual with trial in the `y` axis, which entails aligning all trials to common time and computing ethograms within that new grouping variable.

- Shouldn't you have some sort of date/time column in your data?

In my data, I do. That's the `x` aesthetic I am trying to add. However, I don't want to force this to be a `datetime` column. I believe the minimal information to plot this uses only the discrete sequence on `y`. I might be wrong about this and it might turn out that I have to require `x`. (in which case, that's the main question here)

- It's also not clear what y represents in your data ' aesthetics. Is this a single organism? If so, why is the y axis numeric instead of discrete? And why is behaviour on the y axis in the facet plot? That doesn't make any sense, surely?

The y axis represents whatever is plotted in the y axis. If you want to plot the behaviors separately in one organism as example. Then you should be able to do `aes(y = behavior)` and have them split like that. An application case of this is separating "representative examples" from treatment and control groups (which you can handle through facets).

If you want multiple organisms plotted on y, it should plot all the behaviors on the same y value (that's the example that is currently working).

`y` is numeric in my example because it was a toy example. It needs not be numeric. For example, one would normally use animal `ID`s for example.

I guess the problem is that sometimes `y` serves as `y` axis and `group`, while other times it only serves as `y` axis ?

Comment: I'm struggling a bit to understand what your input / output is supposed to be. Also, shouldn't you have some sort of date/time column in your data? It's also not clear what y represents in your data ' aesthetics. Is this a single organism? If so, why is the y axis numeric instead of discrete? And why is behaviour on the y axis in the facet plot? That doesn't make any sense, surely?

Comment: @AllanCameron Thank you for asking so many clarifying questions, I hope I improved the quality of my request and made things more explicit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got around collaborating and putting together the package (`ggethos`).
It lives here:
https://github.com/matiasandina/ggethos